# Ext.Ajax.request variables

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, extjs

I want to access to some variable(datoslicitproduct) that I declared out ot an Ext.Ajax.request, but I initialize it inside the request.
I have this function :

```
function ExportarExcelproddet(){
var datoslicitaciones = [];
var datoslicitproduct=[];
var datafinal;
var fila=[];
var fila2=[];
var Tipo;
var IdPliego;
ExpGridstore.each(function(r){
    fila.push(r.data['Tipo']);
    fila.push(r.data['IdTxt']);
    fila.push(r.data['Id_Exp']);
    fila.push(r.data['Exp']);
    fila.push(r.data['Org']);
    fila.push(r.data['Fpub'].format('d/m/Y'));
    fila.push(r.data['Fvto'].format('d/m/Y'));
    fila.push(r.data['Estado']);
    datoslicitaciones.push(fila);
    fila=[];
});
var respuestaphp;
var row;
var cont=0;
while(cont<datoslicitaciones.length){
    Tipo=datoslicitaciones[cont][0];
    IdPliego=datoslicitaciones[cont][2];
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url:'./php/ProductosDetalleExp.php',
        params:{cliente:despliegue,operacion:'lote',tipo:Tipo,id:IdPliego},
        success: function(response){
            respuestaphp=Ext.util.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
            var cont2=0;
            var row;
            while(cont2<respuestaphp['data'].length){
                row=respuestaphp['data'][cont2];
                fila2.push(row['IdExpediente']);
                fila2.push(row['Nro_Orden']);
                fila2.push(row['Nombre_Lote']);
                fila2.push(row['Baja']);
                fila2.push(row['Cotiza']);
                fila2.push(row['TotLicitacionsVat']);
                fila2.push(row['TotOfertasVat']);
                datoslicitproduct.push(fila2);
                fila2=[];
                cont2++;
            }
        }
    });
    cont++;
}
console.log(datoslicitproduct);
}
```

And when I call console.log(datoslicitproduct); at the end it appears like this in the console:
[image]

And if i try console.log(datoslicitproduct[0]); it says undefined and I dont understand Why. And I want to know how to access to a specific position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ext.Ajax.request is asynchrone, which mean it doesnt stop and wait for the return of the request. So your console.log is call before the request return. You have to do this in the "success" callback which is call when the request came back.

Comment: Ok,I will try and say something after testing.